# Error using ModelResource: can't set attribute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can't get my head around this error... I'm using the [restframework2](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/tree/restframework2) branch.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in the restframework2 code?

Here's my code:

*resources.py*

```
class TemplateHoursSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TemplateHours
        nested = True

    start = HourField()
    end = HourField()
    employee = EmployeeSerializer()

class TemplateHoursResource(ModelResource):
    model = TemplateHours
    serializer_class = TemplateHoursSerializer
```

*urls.py*

```
url(r'^api/template-hours/$', TemplateHoursResource.as_view(actions={
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})),
url(r'^api/template-hours/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', TemplateHoursResource.as_view(actions={
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})),
...
```

When I visit (or POST to) `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/template-hours/`, I get this error and traceback:

```
AttributeError at /api/template-hours/
can't set attribute
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/template-hours/
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
can't set attribute
Exception Location: C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-    packages\rest_framework\resources.py in wrapped, line 13
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Mathieu\\Development\\django_projects\\hedron\\Scripts',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\virtualenv-1.7.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\Mathieu\\Development\\django_projects\\hedron\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Mathieu\\Development\\django_projects\\hedron\\hedron',
 'C:\\Python27\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
 path(u'C:\\Users\\Mathieu\\Development\\django_projects\\hedron'),
 path(u'C:\\Users\\Mathieu\\Development\\django_projects\\hedron\\hedron\\apps'),
 path(u'C:\\Users\\Mathieu\\Development\\django_projects\\hedron\\hedron\\libs')]
Server time:    di, 9 Okt 2012 22:46:50 +0200

Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111. response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\resources.py" in view
  48. return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  77. return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  324. response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py" in dispatch
  321. response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\resources.py" in list
  74. return self.root_view().list(request, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\resources.py" in root_view
  68. return wrapped(self, self.root_class())
File "C:\Users\Mathieu\Development\django_projects\hedron\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\resources.py" in wrapped
  13. setattr(dest, attr, getattr(source, attr))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/template-hours/
Exception Value: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources and routers are not finished/supported in [the beta of] REST framework 2 yet.  The docs on them are a placeholder for what I want the design to look like, but I'll be removing them from the index today.  Hopefully they'll make it in for 2.0, but I don't see it as at all essential, since you can do everything you need with Views and explicit URLconfs.  Resources & routers just give you a useful shortcut.